# To check if a certain row with certain value exists in table

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this code and it works, but I'm still wondering if there is any other solution which is better and simpler.

```
$sql = "select * from db_member where username = '$name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or error(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) 
{
error("There is no user with name '$name'.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A faster way to do it:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM db_member WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_result($result, 0) == 0) {
    echo 'There is no user with name ' . htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '.';
}
```

Please check http://php.net/pdo for better error handling and query parameters....

I think using mysql_query this way shoulnd't be done anymore..

Answer (score 2):

No, without any other detail this is a good solution. However you could have a look at the following points:

- take care of your indexes. If you could use a where clause on some indexed columns it would be perfect
- if you plan to check the existence of an element before insertion, i'ld rather catch the error than checking like you're doing.
- you could indeed reduce overhead reducing the selection range, like mentionned by another member

rgds